# How to set a Raised Button's Background Color transparent in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

Here is my code,I'd like to set a background color, transparent to my button.

I'd like to add background color to both Raised Button in my code.
I also tried wrapping it with a Container and then applying container's background transparent, but it didn't work.

```
         Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                FadeAnimation(
                  3.4,
                  SizedBox(
                    width: double.infinity,
                    height: 44,
                    child: RaisedButton(
                     color: Colors.white,
                      onPressed: navigateToSignUp,
                      child: Text(
                        'Sign Up',
                        style:
                            TextStyle(color: Colors.blueGrey, fontSize: 24),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),

              SizedBox(height: 10),
                FadeAnimation(
                  3.4,
                  SizedBox(
                    width: double.infinity,
                    height: 44,
                    child: RaisedButton(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      onPressed: navigateToSignIn,
                      child: Text(
                        'Sign In',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 24),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
```

Comment: have you tried Colors.transparent ?

Comment: @Henok  No...  I tried to add background color as transparent

Comment: RaisedButton is deprecated. If you want a transparent background use TextButton instead. It is very simple & the code is shorter

Answer (score 22):

You can use `Opacity` with `black` Color

Like this :

```
 color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.05), //set this opacity as per your requirement
```

It will look much more Attractive

Answer (score 6):

Just use Colors.transparent

```
                RaisedButton(
                  color: Colors.transparent,
                  onPressed: null,
                  child: Text(
                    'Sign In',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 24),
                  ),
                ),
```

Answer (score 6):

Try flat button:

```
            FlatButton(
              color: Colors.transparent,
              splashColor: Colors.black26,
              onPressed: () {
                print('done');
              },
              child: Text(
                'Click Me!',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.lightBlue),
              ),
            ),
```

Answer (score 4):

Using the `colors.transparent` or setting `opacity` property to `0` may not work if you used a gradient as the background. For this reason, the most logical choice for RaisedButton is to set its `elevation` property to `0`.

Like this:

```
RaisedButton(
        elevation : 0, //add this line
        color: Colors.white,
        onPressed: navigateToSignIn,
        child: Text(
          'Sign In',
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 24),
         ),
       ),
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ElevatedButton(
            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
              elevation: 0.0,
              primary: Colors.red.withOpacity(0),
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                    Radius.circular(2),
                  ),
                  side: BorderSide(color: Colors.white)),
            ),
```

Answer (score 1):

use `FlatButton` instead of `RaisedButton` as below:

```
new FlatButton(
              child: new Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
              onPressed: (){}
              )
```

Answer (score 1):

`RaisedButton` by default either it is activer or not it will have greyish background. Try to replace `FlatButton` in place of that `RaisedButton`. Where you could simply pass `color : Colors.transparent` (yet `FlatButton` it self has a transparent background).